# Why do I see duplicate Sorting buttons on my WebGrid?

Tags: jquery, datatables, columnsorting

[image: Duplicate Sorting icons]

I can see two sorting icons displayed superimposing one another, on each header. Can someone please tell me, why I see them and how to remove them.
This WebGrid is in a Partial view and I have defined the DataTable in the partial view too with the same below given definition

here is my datatable definition:

```
$('#Anonymize_UserGrid').DataTable({
        "columnDefs": [
            {
                "targets": [0],
                "visible": false,
                "searchable": false
            },
            {
                "targets": [7],
                "bSortable": false
            }
        ],
        dom: 'Bfrti',
        buttons: [
            {
                extend: 'copy', attr: { id: 'allan' },
                exportOptions: {
                    columns: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
                }
            },
            {
                extend: 'csv',
                exportOptions: {
                    columns: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
                }
            },
            {
                extend: 'excel',
                exportOptions: {
                    columns: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
                }
            },
            {
                extend: 'pdf',
                exportOptions: {
                    columns: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
                }
            },
            {
                extend: 'pageLength',
            },
        ],
        lengthMenu: [
            [10, 25, 50, -1],
            ['10 rows', '25 rows', '50 rows', 'Show all']
        ],

        "oLanguage": {
            "sEmptyTable": 'No Records to display'
        },
        stateSave: true,
        stateSaveCallback: function (settings, data) {
            localStorage.setItem('DataTables_' + settings.sInstance, JSON.stringify(data))
        },
        stateLoadCallback: function (settings) {
            return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('DataTables_' + settings.sInstance))
        }
    });
```